# Self-homeomorphisms of product of the sphere by the circle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

What is the classification of the self-homeomorphisms of the product
of the $n$-sphere by the circle, $S^n\times S^1$, when $n>3$, up to pseudo-isotopy (that is, concordance)?

Comment: You might want to consider making the title more specific

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow Professor Laudenbach.

Comment: I do not understand the 1st question: Are you asking for the description of   the group of self-homeomorphisms of the triangulated surface? Then it is a finite split extension of the direct product of finitely many copies of $Homeo(S^1;T)$ where $T\subset S^1$ is a 3-element subset.  (The types of finite extensions are given by finite subgroups of $O(3)$.) I do not think one can get much beyond this description.

Comment: Prof Laudenbach: I might be wrong, but it looks like these are two independent questions. Might I suggest to ask them separately, and maybe provide a bit more context for the first one?

Comment: Yes, the two questions are independent and not  homework.

Comment: Question 2 comes from dynamical systems (classification of Morse-Smale diffeomorphisms). Only a classification topological classification may be hoped. In the Top category, the question is solved by Moise in dimension 3

Comment: And by Stong-Wang in dimension 4 (Top and Application 106 (2000) 49-56). The difficulty comes from the Kirby-Siebenmann obstruction. Concerning 1), I agree it is poorly written. I am going to post it again.

Comment: After comments suggesting to split the question, the former question 1 was  asked in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262048/ with more context. So I edited to leave only the (formerly) second question. I also added a more specific title and added tags.