# Homeomorphisms of the sphere mapping a geodesic triangulation to another one

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, triangulations

Consider the standard Riemannian 2-sphere $S$, equipped with a geodesic triangulation $T$. Let $L(S,T)$ be the space of homeomorphisms of $S$ which map 
$T$ to a geodesic triangulation. What is the homotopy type of $L(S,T)$?
A similar question has been solved by [E. Bloch, R. Connelly, D. Henderson, Topology 23 (1984), 161-175](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938384900375), when $S$ is a simplicial disc in the plane, and it is a "tour de force"!

This question is on behalf of Jean Cerf, my former advisor,
who is interested in S. Cairns' work.

Comment: The question in the edited title doesn't seem to be the same as the one in the body (and is much easier).

Comment: I have improved the title

Comment: I agree with the change of title. It is better, but I thought of (S,T) as a **structure**, not an object; it was ambiguous.